# catalina.sh on Alpine dockerimage doesn´t start

Tags: docker, dockerfile, tomcat8, alpine-linux

I have this Dockerfile which is an alpine image with tomcat and Java.
Thing is I can´t run the catalina.sh script when I run the container in detached mode. I get following error:

```
$ docker run -d --name login2 -p 8080:8080 alpine:login-o365
8fbd3fda6c2f171045f2338abf4887b5a2374e1f42537717649a3fb6b61c4cb2
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"/opt/tomcat/bin\": permission denied": unknown.
```

After this error I Access the container manually and I check that catalina.sh located in /opt/tomcat/bin has perfectly set the permissions as follow:

-rwxr-x---    1 root     root         21579 Jun  9  2016 catalina.sh

What can it be this error? Is this something related to alpine which is a smaller image or what? This is the Dockerfile that I have:

```
FROM davidcaste/alpine-java-unlimited-jce:jre8


ENV TOMCAT_MAJOR=8 \
TOMCAT_VERSION=8.5.3 \
TOMCAT_HOME=/opt/tomcat \
CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat/bin \
CATALINA_OUT=/dev/null


RUN apk upgrade --update && \
apk add --update curl bash wget && \
curl -jksSL -o /tmp/apache-tomcat.tar.gz http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-${TOMCAT_MAJOR}/v${TOMCAT_VERSION}/bin/apache-tomcat-${TOMCAT_VERSION}.tar.gz && \
gunzip /tmp/apache-tomcat.tar.gz && \
tar -C /opt -xf /tmp/apache-tomcat.tar && \
ln -s /opt/apache-tomcat-${TOMCAT_VERSION} ${TOMCAT_HOME} && \
rm -rf ${TOMCAT_HOME}/webapps/* && \
apk del curl && \
rm -rf /tmp/* /var/cache/apk/*

COPY logging.properties ${TOMCAT_HOME}/conf/logging.properties
COPY server.xml ${TOMCAT_HOME}/conf/server.xml

VOLUME ["/logs"]
EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["/opt/tomcat/bin", "-n", "-c", "catalina.sh"]
```

Comment: Why not use the [official Tomcat images](https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/) ?

Comment: Your CMD instruction is wrong I think. As you did, it would execute in the way: `/opt/tomcat/bin -n -c catalina.sh`.  But `/opt/tomcat/bin` is just a directory. Why not just use `/opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh`.

Comment: Hey, I solved it using official image from tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using this might help

```
CMD /opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh run
```